# Unable to use same SQLite connection across multiple objects in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython, native

I'm working on a Python desktop app using wxPython and SQLite.  The SQLite db is basically being used as a save file for my program so I can save and backup and reload the data being entered.  I've created separate classes for parts of my UI so make it easier to manage from the "main" window.  The problem I'm having is that each control needs to access the database, but the filename, and therefore the connection name, needs to be dynamic.  I originally created a DBManager class that hardcoded a class variable with the connection string, which worked but didn't let me change the filename.  For example

```
class DBManager:
    conn = sqlite3.Connection('my_file.db')

#This could then be passed to other objects as needed

class Control1:
    file = DBManager()

class Control2:
    file = DBManager()

etc.
```

However, I'm running into a lot of problems trying to create this object with a dynamic filename while also using the same connection across all controls.  Some examples of this I've tried...

```
class DBManager:
    conn = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.conn = sqlite3.Connection(filename)

class Control1:
    file = DBManager()

class Control2:
    file = DBManager()
```

The above doesn't work because Python doesn't allow overloading constructors, so I always have to pass a filename.  I tried adding some code to the constructor to act differently based upon whether the filename passed was blank or not.

```
class DBManager:
    conn = None

    def __init__(self, filename):
        if filename != '':
            self.conn = sqlite3.Connection(filename)

class Control1:
    file = DBManager('')

class Control2:
    file = DBManager('')
```

This let me compile, but the controls only had an empty connection.  The `conn` object was `None`.  It seems like I can't change a class variable after it's been created?  Or am I just doing something wrong?

I've thought about creating one instance of DBManager that I then pass into each control, but that would be a huge mess if I need to load a new DB after starting the program.  Also, it's just not as elegant.

So, I'm looking for ideas on achieving the one-connection path with a dynamic filename.  For what it's worth, this is entirely for personal use, so it doesn't really have to follow "good" coding convention.

Comment: Just for clarity, do you really require separate databases, rather than separate `tables` within a single database?

Comment: Yes, separate databases.

Comment: @Megacannon was the below answer in line with what you were looking for? Please have a look and upvote/accept if you found it helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation of your last example

You get `None` in the last example because you are instantiating DBManager in Control1 and Control2 with empty strings as input, and the DBManager constructor has an if-statement saying that a connection should not be created if `filename` is just an empty string. This leads to the `self.conn` **instance variable** never being set and any referal to conn would resolve to the `conn` **class variable** which is indeed set to `None`.

`self.conn` would create an instance variable only accessible by the specific object.
`DBManager.conn` would refer to the class variable and this is what you want to update.

### Example solution

If you only want to keep one connection, you would need to do it with e.g. a. class variable, and update the class variable every time you interact with a new db.

```py
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Connection


class DBManager:
    conn = None

    def __init__(self, filename):
        if filename != '':
            self.filename = filename

    def load(self) -> Connection:
        DBManager.conn = sqlite3.Connection(self.filename) # updating class variable with new connection
        print(DBManager.conn, f" used for {self.filename}")
        return DBManager.conn


class Control1:
    db_manager = DBManager('control1.db')
    conn = db_manager.load()


class Control2:
    db_manager = DBManager('control2.db')
    conn = db_manager.load()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    control1 = Control1()
    control2 = Control2()
```

would output the below. Note that the class variable **conn** refers to different memory addresses upon instantiating each control, showing that it's updated.

```
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x10dc1e1f0>  used for control1.db
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x10dc1e2d0>  used for control2.db
```

Comment: Things are going to get messy, if there's no database close feature with multiple opens. I know that isn't part of your remit, just an observation.

Comment: Yes, definitely a good point @RolfofSaxony . One part to handle that would e.g. be to, in the load method, check whether there is already an open connection and close it before setting up a new. But left it out to keep it a bit shorter, or alternatively use a context manager to handle that.